Proof by contradiction: every real number $x \in[0,\frac { \pi} 2]$ we have $\sin x+\cos x \geqslant 1$
I am asked the following contradiction proof:

Prove by contradiction that for every real number $x \in[0, \frac {\pi} 2]$ we have $\sin x+\cos x \geqslant 1$

I'd like to check if my solution is valid, thank you in advance.
Assume $\sin x+\cos x<1$ for some $x \in[0, \frac{\pi} 2]$. Given $\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x=1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x}+\cos x & <1 \\
\sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x} & <1-\cos  x \\
1-\cos ^2 x & <1-2 \cos x+\cos ^2 x \\
2 \cos x & <2 \cos ^2 x \\
\cos ^2 x & >\cos x \\
\cos x & >1 \quad[\cos x \neq 0, \cos x>0]
\end{aligned}
$$
(contradiction)

From the solution verification tag description: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions."

I think in the end it's better writing $\cos x(\cos x-1)>0$ or you can assume that $x\ne \pi/2$ from the beginning (in fact, for $x=\pi/2$ the inequality is clearly false.

Assume $\sin x+\cos x<1$ for some $x \in[0, \pi / 2]$.
By taking $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\sin^2 x_0+\cos^2 x_0=1+0=1$, so such $x$ cannot be $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
Given $\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x=1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x}+\cos x & <1 \\
\sqrt{1-\cos ^2 x} & <1-\cos  x \\
1-\cos ^2 x & <1-2 \cos x+\cos ^2 x \\
2 \cos x & <2 \cos ^2 x \\
\cos ^2 x & >\cos x \\
\implies\cos x & >1 [\text{since}\ \cos x\neq 0\ \text{for}\ x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})
\end{aligned}
$$

Yes, it's exactly what I suggested in the comments above!

That's nothing more than what the OP, themself, posted????

@amWhy No, I excluded the case when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ to make sure $\cos^2 x>\cos x\implies \cos x>1$, but OP didn't.
